# Searching data in a list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an int List of lotItemIds `(lotItemIdList)`. From `BookingItems` I want to select only such `BookingItems`  whose `BookingItemId` is not present in the `lotItemIds` List.

I wrote an expression as below:

```
 var Booking = context.Bookings.Include(x => x.BookingItems.Select(y => y.LotItem))
                               .FirstOrDefault(x => x.BookingId == BookingId 
                                && x.BookingItems.Any(y => !lotItemIdList.Contains(y.BookingItemId)));
```

But this is selecting all the items even if those are present in the `lotItemIdList`.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of your objects? It looks like a `Booking` has multiple `BookingItems`? Also, just to confirm, are you trying to return `BookingItems` whose `BookingItemId` is not present in the `lotItemIds`; or are you trying to return `Bookings` that have `BookingItems` that are not present in the `lotItemIds`?

Comment: your understanding is correct.
I am trying to return `Bookings` that have `BookingItems` which are not present in the `lotItemIds`

Comment: Thinking about this some more... you say "this is selecting all the items..." but you're calling `FirstOrDefault` - so it can only be returning either zero or one. Did you mean that it is returning all of the BookingItems (as a property of the returned Booking), even the ones that don't match?

Comment: Yes! I found the solution in your posted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you want the Booking itself, then you're on the right track, though you seem to be doing stuff that isn't necessary based on your description. This should work:

```
var bookings = context.Bookings
                      .Where(b => b.BookingItems
                                   .Any(bi => !lotItemIdList.Contains(bi => bi.BookingItemId)));
```

You're getting all Bookings where **any one** of the Bookings' BookingItems has an Id that is not in the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I found what mistake I made :)

Answer (score 0):

From your description, this is what you want:

```
var bookingItems = context.Bookings.Where(b => !lotItemIdList.Contains(b.BookingItemId));
```

Comment: Booking doesn't have BookingItemId - that's a property of BookingItem (at least, I think)